# How do I use nested for loops to create rows that add an additional column to each row in Java?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm taking a CS class and my teacher just taught us about nested for loops in Java.

The end result of my code is:

```
1234567
1234567
1234567
1234567
1234567
```

But what my teacher wants is:

```
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
```

Here's my code:

```
public class NestedLoop2
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        for(int row = 1; row <= 5; row++)
        {
          for(int column = 1; column <= 7; column++)
          {

            System.out.print(column);

          }
          System.out.println();
        }
      }
    }
```

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You should think about the termination condition for the inner for loop -- it probably shouldn't always terminate at 7.

Comment: Can you think of an expression, maybe somehow involving `row`, that you can use in place of that pesky `7` in the inner loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `row` of first loop, in the second loop, and set the initial value of the `row` to `3`, to make the first loop print til the `3`, like this:

```
public class NestedLoop2
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        // The loop begins in row 3, because the first example is: 123
        // And the row will iterate till the 7, to print 5 rows
        for(int row = 3; row <= 7; row++)
        {
          // This loops always begins from 1 and
          // will iterate till the row, to increase the columns
          // Example: 1°: 123, 2°: 1234, etc
          for(int column = 1; column <= row; column++)
          {

            System.out.print(column);

          }
          System.out.println();
        }
      }
    }
```

So, in the inner loop, it will print in the first loop: `123`, because it iterates from `column = 1` til the `row = 3`, and so on.